# Base64 or HEX encoded?

Tags: encoding, compression

I have this string encoded and compressed ([link to full string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ntx7gu7e3bxv9k6/encoded.txt?dl=1))

```
78DAED5DCD72A34610BEA72AEFD0A553725804C3AFB6EC5410425EAA242058767C65256A57556BE1E09FBDE4AD9C532EBB76E287F0BEC6BE40D00F96BDB69761A4C1407AAA5C1620ABFB63FAFB663C9A
(...)
```

And I know that (unencoded and uncompressed) is like this ([link to full string](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zmkozpi68pfr9d7/decoded.txt?dl=1)):

```
<XML>
  <PAGINA NUMERO="0">
    <COPIA NUMERO="1">
      <LINEA NUMERO="1">
        <CAMPO NOMBRE="" POS="3" COMP="EXP" NEGR="NO" SUBR="NO" CBAR="NO" ALTOBAR="0">ORDEN DE PAGO: 
(...)
```

I'm guessig it's compressed and then B64 encoded? I just can't seem to go from one file to the other...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Base64 or HEX encoded?

**Hex**.  Base64 would show upper and lower characters as well as +, /, and =.  This simply shows numbers and a single case of characters (implying case doesn't matter).

Assuming it's hex, you can decode it down to a binary data file using xxd:

```
$ xxd -r -p < encoded.txt > encoded.raw
```

And once you've done that you can use 'file' to guess at what it is:

```
$ file encoded.raw
encoded.raw: zlib compressed data
```

So, yes, compressed with zlib.  You can try to unzip it, only to fail:

```
$ gzip -d < encoded.raw

gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
```

Fortunately, [U&L Stack Exchange provides this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22834/66633):

```
$ printf "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" |cat - encoded.raw |gzip -dc
<XML>

  <PAGINA NUMERO="0">
    <COPIA NUMERO="1">
      <LINEA NUMERO="1">
....
```